# How to export credentials from one jenkins instance to another?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using the credentials plugin in Jenkins to manage credentials for git and database access for my team's builds. I would like to copy the credentials from one jenkins instance to another, independent jenkins instance. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

UPDATE: **TL;DR** Follow the [link](https://itsecureadmin.com/2018/03/jenkins-migrating-credentials/) provided below in a comment by *Filip Stachowiak* it is the easiest way to do it.  In case it doesn't work for you go on reading.

Copying the $HUDSON_HOME/credentials.xml is not the solution because Jenkins encrypts paswords and these can't be decrypted by another instance unless both share a common key.

So, either you use the same encription keys in both Jenkins instances ([Where's the encryption key stored in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38465270/wheres-the-encryption-key-stored-in-jenkins?noredirect=1&lq=1) ) or what you can do is:

1. Create the same user/password, you need to share, in the 2nd Jenkins instance so that a valid password is generated
2. What is really important is that user ids in both credentials.xml are the same. For that (see the credentials.xml example below) for user: *Jenkins* the identifier  `<id>c4855f57-5107-4b69-97fd-298e56a9977d</id>` must be the same in both credentials.xml

   ```
   <com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider plugin="credentials@1.22">
     <domainCredentialsMap class="hudson.util.CopyOnWriteMap$Hash">
       <entry>
         <com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain>
           <specifications/>
         </com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain>
         <java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList>                
           <com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl>
             <scope>GLOBAL</scope>
             <id>c4855f57-5107-4b69-97fd-298e56a9977d</id>
             <description>Para SVN</description>
             <username>jenkins</username>
             <password>J1ztA2vSXHbm60k5PjLl5jg70ZooSFKF+kRAo08UVts=    
             </password>                        
           </com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl>
         </java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList>
       </entry>
     </domainCredentialsMap>
   </com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider>
   ```

Comment: Where does Jenkins store the encryption key? I've been suffering through this for quite some time! :(

Every time I migrate Jenkins, I'd have to re-enter all the credentials!

Comment: Would this work if migrating to a Jenkins server that already has credentials? e.g in the case where one needs to consolidate Jenkins servers.

Comment: @TraianoWelcome IMO when consolidating servers although you still can migrate the credentials from an existing Jenkins you will have to reenter the secrets encripted with the previous credentials.

Comment: @Pedro - I've just found that to be true. I've extracted the secrets from the credentials vault and simply exported them using the jenkins-cli.

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the same problem. What worked for me is I copied the credentials.xml, config.xml and the secrets folder from existing jenkins to the new instance. After the restart of jenkins things worked fine.

Comment: @FilipStachowiak link is broken.

Comment: Check out this [link](https://itsecureadmin.com/2018/03/jenkins-migrating-credentials/).

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me.

Create a job in Jenkins that takes the credentials and writes them to output. If Jenkins replaces the password in the output with ****, just obfuscate it first (add a space between each character, reverse the characters, base64 encode it, etc.)

I used a Powershell job to base64 encode it:

```
[convert]::ToBase64String([text.encoding]::Default.GetBytes($mysecret))
```

And then used Powershell to convert the base64 string back to a regular string:

```
[text.encoding]::Default.GetString([convert]::FromBase64String("bXlzZWNyZXQ="))
```

Answer (score 2):

After trying quite a few things for several days this is the best solution I found for migrating my secrets from a Jenkins 2.176 to a new clean Jenkins 2.249.1 **jenkins-cli** was the best approach for me.

The process is quite simple just dump the credentials from the old instance to a local machine, or Docker pod with java installed, as a XML file (unencrypted) and then uploaded to the new instance.

Before starting you should verify the following:

- Access to the credentials section on both Jenkins instances
- Download the jenkins-ccli.jar from one of the instances (https://www.your-jenkins-url.com/cli/)
- Have User and Password/Token at hand.

> Notice: In case your jenkins uses an oAuth service you will need to
> create a token for your user. Once logged into jenkins at the top
> right if you click your profile you can verify both username and
> generate password.

Now for the special sauce, you have to execute both parts from the same machine/pod:

> Notice: If your instances are using valid Certificates and you want to
> secure your connection you must remove the **-noCertificateCheck**
> flag from both commands.

---

### # OLD JENKINS DUMP #

```
export USER=madox@example.com
export TOKEN=f561banana6ead83b587a4a8799c12c307
export SERVER=https://old-jenkins-url.com/

java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -noCertificateCheck -s $SERVER -auth $USER:$TOKEN list-credentials-as-xml "system::system::jenkins" > /tmp/jenkins_credentials.xml
```

---

### # NEW JENKINS IMPORT #

```
export USER=admin
export TOKEN=admin
export SERVER=https://new-jenkins-url.com/

java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -noCertificateCheck -s $SERVER -auth $USER:$TOKEN import-credentials-as-xml "system::system::jenkins" < /tmp/jenkins_credentials.xml
```

Comment: The password is hidden like <secret-redacted/>.

Comment: i recommend this option since its working for jenkins to cludbees migration and it helps to keeping existing cloudbees cred also.If we go other methods then we have to combine both creds if we have cloudbees creds or we have to recreate that after copy and replace in folder

Comment: With Jenkins 2.176.1 this leaves me with `<secret-redacted />` in the exported file.

Comment: for the `<secret-redacted />`  error could it be related to the secrets structure is different from the typical `system::system::jenkins` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `credentials.xml` available and the old Jenkins instance still running, there is a way to decrypt individual credentials so you can enter them in the new Jenkins instance via the UI.
The approach is described over at the [DevOps stackexchange by kenorb](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2191/how-to-decrypt-jenkins-passwords-from-credentials-xml).

This does not convert all the credentials for an easy, automated migration, but helps when you have only few credentials to migrate (manually).

To summarize, you visit the `/script` page over at the old Jenkins instance, and use the encrypted credential from the `credentials.xml` file in the following line:

```
println(hudson.util.Secret.decrypt("{EncryptedCredentialFromCredentialsXml=}"))
```

Comment: this works for <password> and <secret>, but not <secretBytes>

Answer (score 2):

To migrate all credentials to a new server, from [Jenkins: Migrating credentials](https://itsecureadmin.com/2018/03/26/jenkins-migrating-credentials/):

1. Stop Jenkins on new server.

   ```
   new-server # /etc/init.d/jenkins stop
   ```
2. Remove the *identity.key.enc* file on new server:

   ```
   new-server # rm identity.key.enc
   ```
3. Copy *secret** and *credentials.xml* to new server.

   ```
   current-server # cd /var/lib/jenkins
   current-server # tar czvf /tmp/credentials.tgz secret* credentials.xml
   current-server # scp credentials.tgz $user@$new-server:/tmp/

   new-server # cd /var/lib/jenkins
   new-server # tar xzvf /tmp/credentials.tgz -C ./
   ```
4. Start Jenkins.

   ```
   new-server # /etc/init.d/jenkins start
   ```

Comment: It worked for me! Thanks for your simple tricky solution :)

Answer (score -1):

Migrating users from a Jenkins instance to another Jenkins on a new server -
I tried following  https://stackoverflow.com/a/35603191 which lead to https://itsecureadmin.com/2018/03/26/jenkins-migrating-credentials/. However I did not succeed in following these steps.
Further, I experimented exporting `/var/lib/jenkins/users` (or `{JENKINS_HOME}/users`) directory to the new instance on new server. After restarting the Jenkins on new server - it looks like all the user credentials are available on new server.
Additionally, I cross-checked if the users can log in to the new Jenkins instance. It works for now.

PS: This code is for redhat servers

Old server:

```
cd /var/lib/jeknins
```

or `cd` into wherever your Jenkins home is

```
tar cvzf users.tgz ./users
```

New server:

```
cd /var/lib/jeknins 
scp <user>@<oldserver>:/var/lib/jenkins/user.tgz ~/var/lib/jenkins/.
sudo tar xvzf users.tgz
systemctl restart jenkins
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to copy the $JENKINS_HOME/users folder and the $JENKINS_HOME/credentials.xml file to the other Jenkins instance?

Comment: I'm using ldap authentication for the server itself, but these credentials are for git and database access. Where are they stored? in the plugins folder?

Comment: If you create global credentials (in the Jenkins admin section), they are in the credentials.xml file.

Comment: Did you find that the credentials.xml file was portable?  My experience has shown that usernames/passwords are hashed and that the file from one machine is not recognized by the new machine with the copied file.

Comment: Usually on windows, the default installation is on C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins (==$JENKINS_HOME)