# Checkout Jenkins Pipeline Git SCM with credentials?

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I was following [this tutorial](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/):

```
node {
  git url: 'https://github.com/joe_user/simple-maven-project-with-tests.git'
  ...
}
```

However it doesn't tell how to add credentials. Jenkins does have specific "Credentials" section where you define user user&pass, and then get ID for that to use in jobs, but how do I use that in Pipeline instructions?

I tried with:

```
git([url: 'git@bitbucket.org:company/repo.git', branch: 'master', credentialsId: '12345-1234-4696-af25-123455'])
```

no luck:

```
stderr: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Is there a way configure the creds in pipeline, or do I have to put SSH-keys to Jenkin's Linux user's .ssh/authorized_keys file?

In ideal world I'd like to have a repository for pipeline jobs and repo-keys, then launch Docker Jenkins, and dynamically add these jobs and keys there without having to configure anything in Jenkins Console.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

You can use the following in a pipeline:

```
git branch: 'master',
    credentialsId: '12345-1234-4696-af25-123455',
    url: 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org:company/repo.git'
```

If you're using the ssh url then your credentials must be username + private key. If you're using the https clone url instead of the ssh one, then your credentials should be username + password.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you. I wasn't aware that SSH-url and HTTPS-url require different credentials to work with!

Comment: it was helpful, but `credentialsId` comes from id in [`/var/lib/jenkins/credentials.xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35603191/432903) as I had to struggle to figure it out.

Comment: @prayagupd, you should be able to get the credential ID from the credentials page (`http://yourjenkinsinstall/credentials`). No need to trawl the config files.

Comment: what if I wish to use private and public key? is there any way to use my jenkins keys?

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to re-use credentials defined in a job?

Comment: how to generate this credentialsId?

Comment: For those who ask "How to Generate a credentialsId". Here how to find it. [1. Click on Credentials on Jenkins homepage, 2. You will then see a table with all the credentials you created. 3. ID is in this table]

Comment: For me it couldn't resolve the URL when I set it to start with `ssh://`. Removing it, fixed it.

Comment: All these answers, and nobody links to the documentation for Jenkin's `git` command?

Comment: It worked for me, but I had to remove the ssh:// of the URL

Comment: No need to use `ssh://` in url

Comment: It doesn't work for me.... WorkflowScript: 14: Invalid parameter "branch", did you mean "name"? @ line 14, column 21.
                   git branch: 'staging'

Comment: If we use bitbucket, we can also create a consumer key to substitute username and password. `Key = Username`, `Secret = Password`

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud/#OAuthonBitbucketCloud-Createaconsumer

Comment: Thanks, this helped me as well. I was struggling to checkout in single pipeline mode.

Answer (score 62):

To explicitly checkout using a specific credentials

```
    stage('Checkout external proj') {
        steps {
            git branch: 'my_specific_branch',
                credentialsId: 'my_cred_id',
                url: 'git@test.com/proj/test_proj.git'

            sh "ls -lat"
        }
    }
```

To checkout based on the configured credentials in the current Jenkins Job

```
    stage('Checkout code') {
        steps {
            checkout scm
        }
    }
```

You can use both of the stages within a single Jenkins file.

Comment: how to generate this credentialsId?

Comment: have a look - https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs

Comment: where should i store the credentials file. jenkins sais : Warning: CredentialId "jenkins_key" could not be found.

Comment: @Dinu credentials are created in Jenkins, you should see it in the main menu if the plugin in installed. https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs

Comment: Thank you, this is most useful

Comment: thank you! someone who posted the entire thing rather than just a bit here and bit here, and hoping people magically know what to put for the rest of it.

Comment: Does anyone know how `scm` is handled technically? Is that an argument mapped to an empty map or a string handled specially or ...? I don't find that exact syntax in the docs, but it works obviously. But what is it compared to the map and arguments mentioned in the docs?

Answer (score 41):

Adding you a quick example using git plugin [GitSCM](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin):

```
    checkout([
        $class: 'GitSCM', 
        branches: [[name: '*/master']], 
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
        extensions: [[$class: 'CleanCheckout']], 
        submoduleCfg: [], 
        userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '<gitCredentials>', url: '<gitRepoURL>']]
    ])
```

in your pipeline

```
stage('checkout'){
    steps{
        script{
            checkout
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know how to use a global credentials for the entire team? Or is there a way so that whichever developer is pushing to github, they can provide their credentials without having to expose it in the Jenkinsfile

Comment: You can manage your mechanism related to your own logic in your dev team, and use different credentials keys for each group. for example: If a Github user is in list of 'backend_developers' use <gitCredentialsGroupA> , If Github user in list of 'frontend_developers' use <gitCredentialsGroupB> ,design your mechanism related to your own use case.

Comment: where would you keep these credentials? Is it with the Jenkins Credentials plugin?

Comment: Use Jenkins credentials documentation - https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/

Comment: I’ve searched far and wide for a simple `checkout` example like this one, thank you.

Comment: where does this `checkout` function go in the Jenkinsfile?

Comment: import at as "shared-library" ( `@Library('my-shared-library') _` ) from another repository and connect this library on jenkins configuration as well with the right source control access permissions:
Use this link for more info: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Answer (score 31):

If you want to use ssh credentials,

```
  git(
       url: 'git@github.com<repo_name>.git',
       credentialsId: 'xpc',
       branch: "${branch}"
    )
```

if you want to use username and password credentials, you need to use http clone as @Serban mentioned.

```
    git(
       url: 'https://github.com/<repo_name>.git',
       credentialsId: 'xpc',
       branch: "${branch}"
    )
```

Comment: how to generate this credentialsId?

Comment: I generated the credentials like this: https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent, I added the public key to my git, but where do I have to store this file. Jenkins says: Warning: CredentialId "jenkins_key" could not be found.

Comment: @DinuNicolae please refer `Adding new global credentials -> 7.` at following link.https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/

Comment: Nice Answer. upvote you.   `git(..)` clones remote repository. How can I commit & push current working directory to certain repository, certain branch. I have credenitalsId to target repository.

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth adding to the discussion... what I did that ended up helping me... Since the pipeline is run within a workspace within a docker image that is cleaned up each time it runs. I grabbed the credentials needed to perform necessary operations on the repo within my pipeline and stored them in a .netrc file. this allowed me to authorize the git repo operations successfully.

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '<credentials-id>', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME')]) {
    sh '''
        printf "machine github.com\nlogin $GIT_USERNAME\n password $GIT_PASSWORD" >> ~/.netrc
        // continue script as necessary working with git repo...
    '''
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It solved for me using

```
checkout scm: ([
                    $class: 'GitSCM',
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '******',url: ${project_url}]],
                    branches: [[name: 'refs/tags/${project_tag}']]
            ])
```