# Equivalent block to environment in scripted pipeline with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, block, jobs, environment

I have the following pipeline:

```
    pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        branch = 'master'
        scmUrl = 'ssh://git@myrepo.git'
        serverPort = '22'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Stage 1') {
            steps {
                sh '/var/jenkins_home/contarpalabras.sh'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change the pipeline to "scripted pipeline" in order to use try / catch blocks and have better error management. However i did not find how the equivalent to `environment` block in official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the withEnv block like:

```
    node {
    withEnv(['DISABLE_AUTH=true',
             'DB_ENGINE=sqlite']) {
        stage('Build') {
            sh 'printenv'
        }
    }
}
```

This info is also in the official documentation : https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/#

Comment: Can you use an example to use a git repo?

Comment: this has your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461705/checkout-jenkins-pipeline-git-scm-with-credentials