# Where can i get / generate git project's credentialsId to be used in jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, github, continuous-integration, jenkins-github-plugin

I am trying to checkout my code base using jenkins pipeline.
To do that i need ***'credentialsId'*** for authentication purpose.

```
 stage('Checkout my codebase') {
     steps {
         dir('terraform_src') {
             git(
                 branch: "${GIT_BRANCH}",
                 credentialsId: "${GIT_CREDENTIALS}",
                 url: "git@bitbucket.org:org_name/project_name.git",
             )
         }

     }
 }
```

How can i generate or where can i get the value for 'credentialsId' string?

Currently in my local machine i am using user name and password for authentication purposes for pull and push.

How to create 'credentialsId' using my user name and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to your jenkins machine.

1. Click **Manage jenkins** from the side menu bar in jenkins.
2. Scroll down and you will find **'Manage Credentials'** option with description *'Configure credentials.'*. Click on the *'Manage Credentials'* option.

[image: manage_credentials]

3. Under *'Stores scoped to Jenkins'* section, click on 'Jenkins' hyper-link.

[image: stores]

4. In '*System*' section, click **Global credentials (unrestricted)** .
   [image: global_section]
5. In the next screen, you will see 2 options in the sidebar,

- Back to credential domains
- Add Credentials
  [image: add_creds]

6. Click **'Add Credentials'** and it will open up form. Select 'Kind', 'scope' and fill the username and password. *id* field can be left blank since this will be generated by jenkins if left blank. Provide **valid description** to the key which will be helpful for identifying the key and it's purpose later.

[image: add_data]

7. Go to **Global credentials** page again and you will see the new entry is listed in the table. You can copy the id from the table

Got some inputs from the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461705/checkout-jenkins-pipeline-git-scm-with-credentials/38462645#38462645) answer and corresponding comments.