# Where's the encryption key stored in Jenkins?

Tags: encryption, jenkins, migration, credentials

I am trying to migrate the credentials from one Jenkins to another but usernames/passwords are hashed in ${JENKINS_HOME}/credentials.xml

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35603191/4557537), but the problem is it doesn't explain where would someone find the encryption key in order to successfully migrate credentials.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**: More information.. my ${JENKINS_HOME} is on a separate volume which I detach and re-attach onto the new VM, and it still doesn't work with me.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I found [this analysis](http://xn--thibaud-dya.fr/jenkins_credentials.html) (link is dead as of June 2020, [archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190916195518/http://xn--thibaud-dya.fr/jenkins_credentials.html)) very helpful. In a nutshell:

> Jenkins uses the master.key to encrypt the key hudson.util.Secret.
> This key is then used to encrypt the password in credentials.xml.

When I need to bootstrap new Jenkins instances with some default passwords, I use a template directory tree that contains

- `secrets/hudson.util.Secret` and
- `secrets/master.key`

This works fine.

Comment: I also had to template com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SecretBytes.KEY to make the things work.

Comment: What's the importance of secret.key and secret.not-so-secret key ? @Alex O

Comment: @Kishor U, as far as I can see, `secret.key.not-so-secret` does not contain a key -- it's a boolean indicator file that's used to [fix a security issue](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/3dc13b957b14cec649036e8dd517f0f9cb21fb04)

Comment: Yeah, true. But even though I didn't copy my secret.key, I was able to copy my credentials from one machine to the other.

Comment: @Kishor U, the key in `secret.key` is [deprecated](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/a9aff088f327278a8873aef47fa8f80d3c5932fd) since 2013, so its content probably won't matter any more these days.

Answer (score 10):

Regarding JENKINS migration, I recently experienced this situation and after few testings, my workaround worked for me.

Here is what I did:

1. I moved below files and folders from Source Jenkins to target:

   - $JENKINS_HOME/secret.key
   - $JENKINS_HOME/secrets
   - $JENKINS-HOME/users
   - $JENKINS_HOME/credentials.xml
2. Please note: These files are **not required** to move:

   - $JENKINS_HOME/identity.key.enc
   - $JENKINS_HOME/secrets/org.jenkinsci.main.modules.instance_identity.InstanceIdentity.KEY

otherwise you will see below error after starting Jenkins:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: InstanceIdentity is missing its singleton
```

3. Jenkins will automatically generate those two files. Once started, you should be good.

Comment: what's about the `secrets/master.key` file?

Comment: master.key is not required to migrate. It will be used of newer instance.