# Jenkins credential-id creation

Tags: jenkins

using a couple of username/password, credential-id created by Jenkins is unique and valid just for that Jenkins installation or is the same for each Jenkins installation?

So, if i create a credential-id and put in the pipeline, if I use another jenkins installation I have to regenerate credential-id?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704856/how-to-export-credentials-from-one-jenkins-instance-to-another

Comment: Ok, so the answer is No, the credential-id are not portable, unless you do some trick. Modify the credential.xml file not seems a good idea im my hopinion.

Comment: I think it _does_ mention a way (encryption keys in both Jenkins instances) using which you don't really have to play with `credential.xml` file.